# Running multiple automated load tests of a site to see if code changes / server config make it quicker

Tags: performance, testing, pagespeed, speed-test

Im trying to work out which lazy loading techniques and server setup allow my to server a page quickest, currently im using this workflow :

- Test ping and download speed
- open quicktime screen recorder (so i can review the network tab and load times if there are any anomalies in the data to see what caused them)
- open a new incognito tab with cache disabled and network tab open
- load website
- save screencast
- log ping, download speed, time, date, commit version from git, website loading time into spreadsheet

---

- After i have another test i can the spreadsheet and make a quantified decision on what works.

Running this workflow currently takes about 4 minutes each time i run it (im doing all of these manually, generally i run the same test a couple of times to get an average and then change the variables, image loading js script tweaks and also try it on different VPSs, try it with / without CDN to allow sharding etc.)

Is there an automated approach to doing to ? I guess i could setup a selenium script and run the tests, but i was wandering if there was an of the shelf solution ?

Ideally i would be able to say test it with the following git commits (although i would have to do the server config changes manually) but it would even be quicker i could automate the running, screencasts and logging of the tests.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Jenkins? You can use it to orchestrate your process. It is more like a builder and scheduler of events but might be worth looking into and can integrate with Selenium and other tools (Git too).

Comment: Ive started working with this tool - https://github.com/desktoppr/wbench - which although dosnt fully fill the above brief does a good job